# How can I list files x to y in a directory (Bash)

Tags: bash

This lists all svg files in a directory:

```
ls -1 *.svg
```

But how could I list say, the 50th svg through the 100th svg?

Thank you

Comment: `ls -1 *.svg|sed -ne 50,100p`

Comment: In some corner cases using the output from `ls -1` could cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`ls -1 *.svg | awk "NR >= 50 && NR <= 100"`

Answer (score 0):

This helps?

```
ls -1 *.svg | head -100 |tail -50
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here work perfectly well, but I thought I'd contribute a purely bash-builtin solution:

```
declare -i x=50 y=100 i=0;
for f in *.svg; do
    ((++i>y)) && break;
    ((i>=x)) && echo "$f";
done;
```

Here it is again as a single, compact line:
`declare -i x=50 y=100 i=0; for f in *.svg;do((++i>y))&&break;((i>=x))&&echo "$f";done`